# R formula saved as text (string) in data.frame column. How to nest it and apply per row?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame whose column will hold R formulas as a string.

```
df1

 ID NAME                        FORMULA
  1    a "R formula saved as text string" # will result in a vector of TRUE/FALSE
  2    b "R formula saved as text string" # will result in a vector of TRUE/FALSE
```

i.e `[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE`

I have another data.frame I wish to add a RESULT column that holds the SUM of the result of each formula string.

```
df2

ID NAME RESULT
 1    a    25
 2    b    37
```

**A caveat**: I actually need to do a conditional SUM based on a column (`WEIGHT`) in a another data.frame (`COMISSION_TABLE`).

The following code was a complete fail:

```
df2$RESULT <- sum(ifelse(eval(parse(text=df1$FORMULA)),
                                      yes = COMISSION_TABLE$WEIGHT, no = 0))
```

Can anyone suggest how I could evaluate strings saved as text and apply each per row?

**Great thanks for any assistance!** :)

Comment: Are you able to edit and provide us with an actual sample of `df1` and `COMISSION_TABLE` that includes the formulae, and a sample of what desired output of `df2` looks like given those formulae?  It's a little difficult to help without knowing what your formulae are.